# MVC routing path "?" vs "/"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, routes

I have two routes that return the same page. Both work. Both pages have the correct data - except the carousel on my _layout page doesn't display the images.

`http://localhost:4556/Controller/Function/41` - doesn't work.

`http://localhost:4556/Controller/Function?id=41` - does work.

The route.config file ...

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Does anyone know why this is?

_LAYOUT

```
The carousel I am using is such: 
<div id="myCarousel" class="container carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators"></ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox"></div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

And the image path used in the script is : ImagePath: "../Images/Carousel/default-image.png"

The page that is not displaying the ads properly references the layout page like:

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```

Comment: `Both pages have the correct data` - what does this mean? Are you saying that the ID gets passed to the Action? Can we see the `_Layout` page and what exactly "doesn't work"?

Comment: ControllerController - sounds nice)

Comment: Hi, yes, sorry. The correct ID is passed to the controller and the data in my 'not-layout' page is all correct and being passed through correctly.  More to come.... re layout page...

Comment: Doesn't work = the carousel displays images as a broken link.

Does: The images in the carousel display.

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the following route configured:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "GetGift",
    "{controller}/{action}/{priceId}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "GetGift" });
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetGift(int priceId)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

When I navigate to this url: `http://localhost:20441/Home/GetGift/1` I end up in the above action method. The same thing happens when I try `http://localhost:20441/Home/GetGift?priceId=1`. SO I can choose which format to use.

Configuring routes can be a dark art, but I tend to declare them as specifically as I can (in my example, I'm specifically mentioning `{priceId}` in the route to avoid using the ambiguous `{ id }` ), to help narrow down the choices which the routing engine has to iterate through, and avoid confusion i.e. the route engine picks a different route then I expected.

Comment: Thank you so much.
Am I understanding correctly that I should make sure all my calls to the controller are of the same format?

It is so strange that the data and everything comes though correctly, it is just the carousel that bombs.

Thanks again for your help. Appreciate it.

Comment: The default route ` "{controller}/{action}/{id}` could be the only route you ever need for a site. However, when you start passing data around in the url, that's when you want to start looking into using more routes e.g. `{controller}/{action}/{priceId}` to cover the available url's.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I asked a very clever guy I worked with.

My images needed to be referenced with @Url.Content(etc..)

Thanks to everyone who answered me! :)